# MySQL subquery from another database where table name depends on main query

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi I am trying to sub query a table(name: table_guest_id) from another database where id from the table name depends on the main query.
Here is the set up of my databases:

- Three tables: events, profile, table_guest_id
- Two databases: main and guest(dbName below just to make it clear)
- main contains: events and profile
- guest contain: table_guest_id(where id = e.ID)

And this is my sql code:

```
    public function getListAttendee($user)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT p.name e.user, e.ID, e.date 
                FROM events e, profile p
                WHERE p.user_id=e.user AND e.event_date >= CURDATE() 
                AND (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                     FROM dbName.table_guest_[??note: need to insert e.ID??] a 
                     WHERE a.event_id=e.ID AND a.user_id='{$user}' AND
                     a.status='invited') > 0";
     }
```

I have put a note where ID OR e.ID will be inserted, but it is not working yet.
Please let me know if you have a different solution on how to sub query a table where the name of the table depends on the main query values.
IS THIS IDEA EVEN POSSIBLE?

Comment: Silly question probably - As you can only create a connection to a single database using `mysqli_` or `PDO` how do you get the query to know about the second database, as it only knows about the tables that exist on the database it is connected to

Comment: Hi Riggs, thanks for the reply, so my intention was query the second DB where all the tables are name table_guest_id, where id depends on the event id where I will get from the main query. Do you think this is not possible?

Comment: I will watch this question with interest, to see if anybody can educate us both on this subject. The words External and maybe Federated come to mind but only vaguely

Comment: I think you might have to create 2 seperate connections, one to each database. Then query one and possibly store that data in an array, or a temporary table if its too large for an in memory array. Then query the second database and use PHP to match up the 2 results if you use an array, or query from a single database using the temporary table

Comment: Ok I will try that option, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to perform variable substitution on a SQL table name.

```
  FROM dbName.table_guest_[??note: need to insert e.ID??] a
```

You Can't Do That™ directly in SQL. You'll need to write your php code to generate that table name, or use the string-processing feature that the MySQL team calls [*prepared statements.*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

If your different databases are hosted on the same MySQL server, you can write queries that refer to more than one of them at a time. Simply give the database name as well as the table name.  For example, if you have databases `db1` and `db2` you can do this.

```
 SELECT whatever
   FROM db1.events e
   JOIN db2.user_118 u ON whatever = whatever
```

Comment: That is the appropriate word variable substitution within the query. It seems you are right, that is a big limitation. Thanks Ollie for the answer.